# Multiple IF conditions in Cassandra lightweight transactions/CAS

Tags: cql, cassandra-2.1, paxos

So I'm trying to do a CAS (compare-and-set) type operation in Cassandra, where I want to do a data update only if a particular non-primary-key column is `NULL` or `< ?` where `?` is supplied by client-side code.

How do I do this? Something like the following **doesn't** work:

```
UPDATE my_dbs.foo SET col1=5 WHERE id=1 IF (col1 = NULL OR col1 < 4);
```

The error I get is similar to the following:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:149 no viable alternative at input '(' (...
```

How do I do this in Cassandra 2.0/2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OR logical operator is not supported in the IF clause. From the documentation [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_g4h_qzq_xj__synopsis_unique_35):

Synopsis:

> UPDATE keyspace_name.table_name
>
> USING option AND option
>
> SET assignment, assignment, ...
>
> WHERE row_specification
>
> ***IF*** column_name = literal ***AND*** column_name = literal . . .
>
> IF EXISTS

Perhaps either do two separate updates to cover both cases, or populate col1 with a default non-null value at insertion given this doesn't compromise your application logic.

Comment: thanks so much, the latter sounds like a much better option for getting not-so-expensive reads- your former option depends a lot on consistency level of the read, imo.

Comment: @Nishant Kelkar you're very welcome. Yes I agree with you on the first option I mentioned. It would either be expensive reads or some sort of enforcement in the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do IF conditions with several "OR". Just use `if field in (value1, value2)`

`UPDATE my_dbs.foo SET col1=5 WHERE id=1 IF col1 in (null, 1, 2, 3);`

Comment: I have found that (at least in driver v3.17.0) this works fine as a SimpleStatement, but it doesn't work with prepared statements. For TEXT columns at least, IF col1='' is treated differently to IF col1=null, but None and '' are both serialized to the same byte sequence when the tuple parameter is bound to the prepared statement.